# Cryptic Country 1

Tags: riddle, knowledge

A Caesar of a different kind originates from me

My strip on my left is pretty obvious to see

I stretch pretty far, but not as long as ignorants think

The highest card value's thoughts do not tickle me pink

Name the country

Comment: Caesar cat food origin:_____

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you perhaps:

> Mexico?

A Caesar of a different kind originates from me

> Caesar Salad

My strip on my left is pretty obvious to see

> There is a strip of land on the left side of mexico, pretty obvious

I stretch pretty far, but not as long as ignorants think

> Not quite sure yet, maybe people think Mexico extends into Latin America?

The highest card value's thoughts do not tickle me pink

> Also not sure, working on it. Maybe referring to Mexico's independence from Spain, meaning that they do not like the King of Spain

Comment: For, I stretch pretty far, I think you could put that Mexico was in control of Alta California until the American- Mexican war

Comment: I guess, but I don't know many "ignorants" who even know about Alta California.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Comment: Either way, I think the first two clearly point to mexico

Comment: Yeah unless it is Caesar cat food, strip filets

Comment: Maybe, but isn't that spelled "Cesar"? Also, I don't think that has anything to do with a strip on the Left side of something

Comment: Ohhh, oops, sorry

Comment: No worries. Now we just wait for OP to come back

Comment: I'll give you a hint for the fourth line. Think about what the name is for a card of high value in games like Pinochle and poker

Comment: Line 4: trump suit

Answer (score 0):

Would you be

> Russia

A Caesar of a different kind originates from me

> Julius Caesar was a ruler- the obvious "Caesar", and the tsar (csar, or "Caesar") is the title for Russia's ruler, similar to "king".

My strip on my left is pretty obvious to see

> The whole Europe & Norway/Sweden/Finland area

I stretch pretty far, but not as long as ignorants think

> Russia is really long and really big.

The highest card value's thoughts do not tickle me pink

> The famous Anastasia & Romanovs were the "kings" of Russia and were... eliminated.

Comment: That might be a bit of a stretch, but It could work

Comment: As long as it's actually considered a country in this regard-

Comment: Incorrect, but good thoughts

Answer (score -1):

Are you perhaps

> Canada?

Because

> Canada stretches till Russia by Alaska..

Comment: No, it isn't Canada